# Selenium Python minimize browser window

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know how to call a method to maximize window from driver object.

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

But what method should I use when I need to minimize browser window (hide it)?
Actually, driver object hasn't maximize_window attribute.
My goal to work silently with the browser window. I don't want to see it on my PC.

Comment: Do you mean to set browser window to minimal size or to hide it?

Comment: @Andersson Yes hide it. Like '.' action in Windows.

Comment: @FedirAlifirenko Is your Question still unanswered? Can you consider showing us your work please & the exact manual steps you are trying to perform? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try a headless browser? Chrome headless or PhantomJS.

http://phantomjs.org/

Keep in mind that development is suspended for Phantom js. You may want to use other alternatives if it doesn't work or gives errors -

https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers

A headless browser is a web browser without a GUI.

Answer (score 22):

Option 1: Use driver.minimize_window()

Option 2: Use --headless

Example 1:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("enter your url here")
```

Example 2:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.minimize_window()
driver.get("enter your url here")
```

Comment: After chrome version 109, the '--headless' command was updated to '--headless=new'

Answer (score 9):

I would like to give a suggestion and make you correct that there's a method to minimize the window as you are required to do.

```
driver.minimize_window()
```

I would also like to mention that this will definitely work in python3, hope you were working in python.

Answer (score 5):

Just `driver.minimize_window()` or use a headless browser as PhamtonJS or Chromium.

Example:

```
PROXY_SERVER = "127.0.0.1:5566" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r"/usr/bin/opera" # path to opera executable
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY_SERVER)
driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=r"/home/prestes/Tools/operadriver_linux64/operadriver", options=options)
driver.minimize_window()
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print(html)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks but it isn't minimize window. It only sets position.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. for that you can try `driver.set_window_size(0, 0)`

Comment: Thanks, Andersson already posted this variant but it's still not solution for my question.