# How to stop Python Selenium from maximizing the window on download

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created a code to download programmatically files from a website, each time a download occurs the window running with selenium maximizes and i need to minimize it to continue work.

How can i prevent it from maximizing on each download event?

Comment: Have you tried adding a headless option to the driver?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644500/selenium-python-minimize-browser-window

Comment: @LancelotduLac If i add --headless will the browser still run or will it be hidden entirely? Cause i need the browser actually to showup for in case of a captcha...

Comment: I dont understand the question. Why does the window maximize on download? is this an expected app behaviour from the devs? You can try driver.set_window_size(0, 0) to set a custom window size each time download happens

Comment: @ShivamMishra Actually i don't know, this is the behaviour of the browser.
When a download occurs on the test browser - it just suddenly opens the browser window interrupting my workflow.

Comment: try reproducing manually. If it does not match the expected behavior of the application, this needs to be fixed from developers

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to write this line of code after the line of code which initialises download event

```
driver.minimize_window()
```

This will automatically minimize window after each download event

**Note:** Minimize function is only available in Selenium 4, so if you are using previous versions of Selenium then this will not work

Also note that the above snippet is compatible with Python. To find the minimize function of of your respective language, please search GOOGLE BABA

PEACE